# Have someone a workaround for an Selection.Replace issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the replace funktion in VBA

In one columns from my table there some Values like 10,5m or 15,354m

I want to replace that with an simple vba command
like this

```
Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="m", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
```

but then my Values are 105 or 15354

When I use the build in command in excel without VBA it works like it should.

How Can I fix it?

Here is a test file with an Import txt file, where I collect the data
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wtn83rs83dx455s/AABH7MmHKQxVJA6Tx7KVwM54a?dl=0

Thanks for your help

Comment: When I run your code I come up with 10,5 and 15,354

Comment: Select the column manually, right click, Format Cells and check its format.

Comment: @Davesexcel with version from excel to you use, I think it´s maybe an excel apple problem?

Comment: @Error1004 I try different solutions, but it have no effect

Comment: Could you please upload the document?

Comment: @Error1004 in my description is now a link to the test file

Comment: You forgot to mention about the formatted cells.

Comment: @Davesexcel what do you mean

Answer (score 1):

The values are not actually 10,5m or 15,354m but 10,5 and 15,354
it's a formatting thing that shows the "m" even if its not part of the value. 
the reason is that your import macro sets the range format:

```
Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "#0.0""m"""
```

change it to:

```
Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "#0.0"
```

..and the "m" is gone.

Comment: not really, it have no effect m stays... after all it should be formated liked that with an m at the back

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, at first I must replace "," with a "." after that I can replace "m" with "".

And after that I can set the correct format "#0.0""m"""

```
Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
        Selection.Replace What:="m", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "#0.0""m"""
```

bye